# Design pattern for network connections and requests

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-networking

Im developing an app that have **alot of web requests**. Such as `download` or `upload` files , `REST requests` and etc.
I want to save all of this functions in a `class` like a helper and only just import the class and call functions that i need them in my activities.
something like a custom library for web requests i mean.
Is there any **Design pattern** for this? 
(I hope i explain my idea well)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: sorry ! but i don't looking for library , i wrote my functions and now i want to collect all of them in a single class ! its make my codes more cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Consider using these libraries:

- [**Robospice**](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) - for asynchronous network calls
- [**Retrofit**](https://github.com/square/retrofit) - for REST calls
- [**OkHttp**](https://github.com/square/okhttp) - good HTTP/SPDY client
- [**Picasso**](https://github.com/square/picasso) - for image loading and caching
- [**Jackson**](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) - to work with JSON

You can use custom `IntentService` class to hanle all networking there, starting this service from UI and passing apropriate `ACTION` to perform.

And of course i would suggest you watch [**this video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) from Google I/O 2010 and use `REST Pattern A` described there in **EVERY** network app you make.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Chain of Responsibility` pattern for building up requests and then executing them. See some details [here](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/chain.html).

Of course, using just this one pattern would not be enough. It should be used in conjunction with an `Observer`, `Factory`, `Proxy` and maybe some others. Just start developing with [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) in mind.